# Why I Get "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.DatePicker.callOnValueChange"?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, nosuchmethoderror

I get this error when user choose date with "DatePickerDailog".

I sow this error in my application logs.

Probably the application runs on Android 4.4.4 version.

Code:

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener  = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()     {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            monthOfYear++;
            birthDate = year + "-" + monthOfYear + "-" + dayOfMonth + "T" + "00:00:00Z";
            tvBirthDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year);
        }
    };
```

Logs:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.DatePicker.callOnValueChange
1       at android.widget.DatePicker$OnDateChangeListener.onValueChange(DatePicker.java:162)
2       at android.widget.NumberPicker.notifyChange(NumberPicker.java)
3       at android.widget.NumberPicker.setValueInternal(NumberPicker.java)
4       at android.widget.NumberPicker.scrollBy(NumberPicker.java)
5       at android.widget.NumberPicker.onTouchEvent(NumberPicker.java)
6       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java)
7       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
8       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
9       at android.widget.NumberPicker.dispatchTouchEvent(NumberPicker.java)
```

Comment: post code and error log cat

Comment: Can you reproduce this yourself or is it just a random error in your userbase?

Comment: I can't reproduce it myself. But still, one of my users get this error..